# Bresser Saurus (aka Flashforge Finder) thermocouple broken

Tags: troubleshooting, flashforge-finder

The thermocouple on my 3D printer broke (one of the cables broke from the brass part that attaches to the heatblock). I managed to get it working and I was looking for other thermocouples while I had my machine working.

The thing is that it broke againg after two or three uses, and now it's a mess - it cannot be repaired anymore by mortal means. So the only solution is to buy a new one. And here it comes the problem: both the Flashforge Finder and the Bresser Saurus are out of production (only the Flashforge Finder 3 is out, and it has different pieces than the other Finders).

I managed to buy one thermocouple from Aliexpress but it turned out that it was not compatible (marking 50ºC at room temperature). I have tried other thermocouples, but I am not able to find it (and my knowledge on this is more or less nothing).

As I understand, the Bresser Saurus is just a repaint of the Flashforge Finder 2. But this is where things get strange, as I am unable to make anything from FF2 work on my Saurus. I've contacted the technical service of both Bresser and Flashforge and the answer is that they cannot provide me with even the type of thermocouple that it is used on my machine.

I hope that someone knows this, because if not, I am worried I may need to buy another printer if I want to continue printing.

[image: Bresser Saurus Motherboard]

Comment: If you can, please also add a photo of the original (broken) "thermocouple", as it *might* help identification, be it a thermocouple, NTC thermistor or RTC probe.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) eight types: B, E, J, N, K, R, T, & S type. Each type has different operating temperatures and characteristics.

K type thermocouples appear to be the most common (for our purposes), as they have the required temperature range useful for a 3D printer. You will need to know which type the printer originally came with. The original was probably just a generic thermocouple, so you should be able to get a replacement, but the type must match.

Also note that the original "thermocouple" may not have been an actual thermocouple... Often *NTC thermistors* or *RTD probes* can be used instead (to reduce costs). So you will need to check this too.

This thread has some (hopefully) useful information (assuming that the Bresser Saurus *actually* is just a rebadged Flashforge Finder 2): [FF Finder thermocouple replacement](https://www.3dprintingforum.org/flashforge/120200-ff-finder-thermocouple-replacement).

This [post #2](https://www.3dprintingforum.org/flashforge/120200-ff-finder-thermocouple-replacement?p=120236#post120236) states that **K-type thermocouples** are used

> A thermo couple device is polarity sensitive, try connecting the wires the opposite way round.
> The FF Dreamer & Finder use a K-Type thermo couple. the wires are made of specific dissimilar materials that generate a voltage when heated. The Mother-Board detects this volttage change & works out the temperature.
> All thermo-couples are polarity sensitive, & iff connected the wrong way round they will give some very odd readings indeed.
> Note also that there are many types of thermocouple that each react to different temperature ranges.

and this [post #3](https://www.3dprintingforum.org/flashforge/120200-ff-finder-thermocouple-replacement?p=120288#post120288) states that **NTC thermistors** are used in older models of the Flash Forge Finder:

> It turns out, even though my Finder was bought recently (Flashforge store on Amazon), it is an old model and actually has a NTC thermistor instead of a thermocouple! Flashforge USA knows nothing about this, and I didn't have much luck with the Chinese contact either. The only two replacement parts to be ordered from them are both thermocouples-- in either M3 or M4 thread.

That post also includes some links to replacements.

Note also the thread and (to a lesser extent) the connector are important: Either M3 or M4 threads are used, so you will need to verify that as well, before making a purchase.